# How do I find what stored procedures contain a piece of text

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to find out what stored procedures contain a piece of text (sort of like Grep for MS SQL). So that I can find the name of a table and replace it.

For example if I wish to find what stored procedures on my database contain the table name "clients_users"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code will help to find all the Stored Procedures (SP) which are related to one or more specific tables. sp_help and sp_depends does not always return accurate results.

----Option 1

```
SELECT DISTINCT so.name  
FROM syscomments sc  
INNER JOIN sysobjects so ON sc.id=so.id  
WHERE sc.TEXT LIKE '%tablename%'
```

----Option 2

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.name, o.xtype  
FROM syscomments c  
INNER JOIN sysobjects o ON c.id=o.id    
WHERE c.TEXT LIKE '%tablename%'
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Thanks marc, that was a great suggestion as I was wondering how to do this formatting.

Answer (score 1):

One way for sql server 2005 and up

```
SELECT NAME
FROM sys.procedures
WHERE OBJECT_DEFINITION(object_id) LIKE '%clients[_]users%'
```

you need [] around _ since _ means any character when you do a wild card search

Answer (score 0):

Executing the following query will yield the results required. Replace foobar with the text you need to find in the stored procedure.

```
SELECT ROUTINE_NAME, ROUTINE_DEFINITION 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES 
    WHERE ROUTINE_DEFINITION LIKE '%foobar%' 
    AND ROUTINE_TYPE='PROCEDURE'
```